# What is the difference between randi(x,y,1) and randsample(x,y,true)?

Tags: matlab, function, random, built-in

I usually use `randsample`, but I came across `randi`, and I'm wondering if there is any difference.

For example, these seem to be both picking random numbers from [1,10] and returning a 10 x 1 vector:

```
n = randi(10,10,1);
n2 = randsample(10,10,true);
```

What is the difference between these two lines of code?

Comment: They give the same result. Probably `randi` is a little faster

Comment: Why is randi probably faster?

Comment: Because `randsample` is written in Matlab, whereas `randi` is a built-in function

Comment: `randsample` uses `randi` within it alongwith other stuff

Comment: If the Levenshtein distance is a valid measure of "difference", it's `11`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider two sources:

1. The documentation of `randsample`, where we see:

   > `y = randsample(s,...)` uses the stream `s` for random number generation. `s` is a member of the `RandStream` class. Default is the MATLAB® default random number stream.
2. The source code of `randsample` (`Copyright 1993-2010 The MathWorks, Inc.`) we find the following behavior for the case when the 3rd input is `true`:

   ```
   % Sample with replacement
   case {true, 'true', 1}
       if n == 0
           if k == 0
               y = zeros(0,1);
           else
               error(message('stats:randsample:EmptyPopulation'));
           end
       elseif isempty(w)
           if defaultStream
               y = randi(n,k,1);
           else
               y = randi(s,n,k,1);
           end

       else
           % Irrelevant case as it concerns weighting which randi doesn't support.
       end
   ...
   ```

So from the above we learn the following:

- In some cases the input of `randsample` is just redirected to `randi`.
- There's a slightly different behavior for edge cases, like `randi(0,0,1)` (which errors) vs. `randsample(0,0,true)` (which outputs an empty array).

Generally  `randsample` has more features: it is able to handle a non-default [`RandStream`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randstream.html), and weighting.